# Why do the technicians on duty not care about what happening to Robocop when he's Dreaming?

Tags: plot-explanation, robocop

In the *Robocop* (1987) there is a scene with Robocop resting in his chair & dreaming about the badguy Boddicker. His body shakes in this dream state

The monitoring systems in the room indicate strange patterns and noises but the technicians on duty did not seem care about what was happening to Robocop.

Why do the technicians on duty not care about what is happening?

Is it because they didn't see anything or hear the noises?

Comment: They definitely don't think of him as a human being, at that point, just some sort of freakishly-created machinery. Maybe that's why they don't especially care.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is heavily implied that they do not notice what is happening at first.

At the 0:45 mark in your video, they suddenly notice something, and they do care about it; so they were not simply ignoring it before. They were so focused on their reading and eating that they didn't pay attention to things happening around them.

This is a [common joke/trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ObliviousJanitorCut) in movies; where characters are humorously too focused on their own thing to notice something happening around them. Robocop is a satire film, and here it is playing up the angle that characters who have an important job of monitoring Robocop's brain activity are too lazy/busy to notice, instead having smalltalk about the news.